# How to compare serialized patterns in SPMF library?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-mining

We used CloSpan to mine frequent patterns from historical data. Thats working fine.

We now want to match the frequent patterns with patterns we generate from real time data.

We have two serialized sequences:

A 1 -1 2 -1 3 -2

B 2 -1 3 -2

And we want to determine if B is a sub sequence/pattern of A.

What are the exact methods/classes we need to use to do that?

Thx